# Embed images as data/base64 in a div block

Tags: html, css

Is it good practice to embed images as data/base64 in a div block ?

```
<div style="background-image" url(data:image/png;base64, ...)></div>
```

Comment: Use like this `<div style='background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0.......)repeat-x center;'></div>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i think, this has some cool benefits.

- this improves offline access of image .
- this eliminates the need for separate HTTP requests for each image. This can potentially improves page load times, especially for small images.

Comment: ... and it can also be absolutely counter-productive, if the same image is used across multiple pages - because then you eliminate any possibility of properly _caching_ the image.